# import data with a column of type Pig Map into spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I'm trying to import data that has a column of type Pig map into a spark dataframe, and I couldn't find anything on how do I explode the map data into 3 columns with names: street, city and state. I'm probably searching for the wrong thing. Right now I can import them into 3 columns using StructType and StructField options.

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
   StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
   StructField("name", StringType, true),
   StructField("address", StringType, true))) #this is the part that I need to explode


val data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
     .option("header", "false")
     .option("delimiter", ";")
     .schema(schema)
     .load("hdfs://localhost:8020/filename")
```

Example row of the data that I need to make 5 columns from:

```
328;Some Name;[street#streetname,city#Chicago,state#IL]
```

What do i need to do to explode the map into 3 columns so id have essentially a new dataframe with 5 columns ? I just started Spark and I've never used pig. I only figured out it was a pig map through searching the structure [key#value].

I'm using spark 1.6 by the way with scala. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the pig format (there may even be libraries for it), but some good ol' fashioned string manipulation seems to work. In practice you may have to do some error checking, or you'll get index out of range errors.

```
val data = spark.createDataset(Seq(
(328, "Some Name", "[street#streetname,city#Chicago,state#IL]")
)).toDF("id", "name", "address")

data.as[(Long, String, String)].map(r => {
    val addr = (r._3.substring(1, r._3.length - 1)).split(",")
    val street = addr(0).split("#")(1)
    val city = addr(1).split("#")(1)
    val state = addr(2).split("#")(1)
    (r._1, r._2, street, city, state)
}).toDF("id", "name", "street", "city", "state").show()
```

which results in

```
+---+---------+----------+-------+-----+
| id|     name|    street|   city|state|
+---+---------+----------+-------+-----+
|328|Some Name|streetname|Chicago|   IL|
+---+---------+----------+-------+-----+
```

I'm not 100% certain of the compatibility with spark 1.6, however. You may end up having to map the `Dataframe` (as opposed to `Dataset`, as I'm converting it with the `.as[]` call), and extract the individual value's from the `Row` object in your anonymous `.map()` function. The overall concept should be the same though.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I managed to do it with just map and split. I was thinking too much about Pig Map.